# (React Native) Change color to a text after onPress() it

Tags: react-native, text, react-navigation, onpress

I have a drawer with some text elements created dynamically.
I would like to select an item from the drawer, "**show selected item**" (like change the color of the text of that item) and re-change it to default when another one item is selected.

The text that I'd like to "change onPress" is inside the `<TouchableWithoutFeedback>` tag (i'm rendering some HTML code with react-native-render-html)

```
 <FlatList
          ItemSeparatorComponent={this.FlatListItemSeparator}
          data={this.state.data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            //on touch --> open article (call _onTextPress)
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.navigateToScreen('Category', {id: item.id, title: item.name})}>
              <View style={styles.categories}>
                <HTML html={'<p style="color:#fd3a18; font-size:20px;"><strong>'+item.name+'</strong></p>\n'}/>
              </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
          )}
          keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id.toString()}
        />
```

```
  navigateToScreen(routeName, params) { 
    return () => { 
      this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName, params }))
      this.props.navigation.closeDrawer();

    };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to change the color of selected item

```
//Add Selected Item to the State
state = {selectedItemId:'myId'}
// Change The State Whenever Selected
 navigateToScreen(routeName, params) { 
    this.setState({selectedItemId:params.id})
    return () => { 
      this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName, params }))
      this.props.navigation.closeDrawer();

    };
  }
```

Now Change the color conditionally.

```
          <FlatList
          ItemSeparatorComponent={this.FlatListItemSeparator}
          data={this.state.data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            //on touch --> open article (call _onTextPress)
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.navigateToScreen('Category', {id: item.id, title: item.name})}>
              <View style={styles.categories}>
                <HTML html={`<p style="color:${this.state.selectedItemId == item.id ? "red" : "#fd3a18"}; font-size:20px;"><strong>'+item.name+'</strong></p>\n`}/>
              </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
          )}
          keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id.toString()}
        />
```

Comment: thanks for the  answer :)
there's a problem... the id i'm passing as parameter isn't the element i pressed's id... How can i pass it?

Comment: @AndreaFavero Can you show this.state.data in your post ?